# Are these the minimum files to run JQuery TE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jhtmlarea

I am trying to use the JQuery TE with the minimum configuration.
I downloaded the sample folder which had a bunch of files I am not sure why they are needed e.g. jquery-1.3.2.min.js,jquery-1.3.2.min-vsdoc.js etc.
Anyway right now I have in my scripts directory only the following:

> jquery-1.3.2
>   jHtmlArea-0.7.5

In my styles directory I removed everything and now have only the following:

> jHtmlArea.css
>   jHtmlArea.png
>   jHtmlArea_Toolbar_Group__Btn_Select_BG.png
>   jHtmlArea_Toolbar_Group_BG.png

I hope that I did not do something stupid by removing the other files but the following works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() {  
  $("textarea").htmlarea(); // Initialize jHtmlArea's with all default values     
 });  
</script>
```

[image]

So is my configuration (the fact that I removed all these files correct)?

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2 was released early 2009 (http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/) so you are looking at some seriously ancient stuff. I would recommend you to look at http://www.tinymce.com or some other modern editor instead thats still being developed and improved.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjogren:You mean that this text editor is "abandoned" from JQuery team?I working on a project that uses jquery and would prefer to avoid using another library since my requirements of this editor are to the bare minimum

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjogren:I also tried CDN:`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>` but still same result

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjogren:Figured out the problem. I updated OP to ask if there could be any issue in removing all these files

Comment: -min is minified copy of the developer version which u already have. vsdoc is for intellisense in visual studio. So, your running code is not affected by these. Not sure about styles folder. check if there is any image of css that your code might need. you will see 404 errors in chrome console.

Comment: @Jim: it doesn't look like "jQuery TE" was written by the jQuery team. All their stuff is, "Copyright 2013 The jQuery Foundation", but jQuery TE is "Copyright 2013 Fatih Koca".

Comment: Yes as @Douglas points out, jQuery TE is a plugin and almost all plugins are maintained by others and not the jQuery Team. Moreover, the code you showed isn't from jQuery TE but from http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com.

Comment: @Douglas:But I only included jquery in my page.Not any other library

Comment: Ah, yes, Karl is right, you're not using jQuery TE at all. You're using the jHtmlArea plugin. (Technically jHtmlArea-0.7.5.js contains the jHtmlArea library, which is exposed through the .htmlarea() jQuery plugin, but that distinction isn't terribly important.)

Comment: @Douglas:I see.Should I use jQueryTE over htmlArea?

Comment: I've not used either of them, but from a brief look at their demos, I'd be more tempted by TE, even if the site is a rip-off of an older version of the jquery site.