# How can I configure only the options I need in the JQuery TE toolbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking into choosing an html editor. I have tried jHtmlArea ([thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889207/are-these-the-minimum-files-to-run-jquery-te) that it was JQueryTE.
Anyway I also tried JQuery TE which is simple to use, just call the jqte().
But I can not seem to find how to set which function of the toolbar I need (like I can do in jHtmlArea).
How can I configure only the options I need in the toolbar?

Comment: never seen this plugin before, but am impressed with documentation format. All the options and examples of setting them are outlined well...what part is confusing?

Comment: @charlietfl:I can not seem to find how to display the **minimum** buttons in the toolbar.E.g. not show link or subscript options etc. Also I have to say that your comment that this plugin is unknown start to concern me...

Comment: don't read unknown into it...plugins get added to web world constantly, nobody uses them all, and is dependent on what type of work usually do. All the options show what default is...if don't wnt default add that option to your config object. There is example for `link: false` right in docs  http://jqueryte.com/documentation#option-link

Comment: make one object, separate key value pairs with a comma, and that's it

Comment: @charlietfl:Where does it say that here http://jqueryte.com/documentation? Would it be possible to show me the example?

Comment: that's the way all plugins work

Comment: @charlietfl:I am jquery newbie to be honest.Stuggling with the basics

Comment: Look in source code of demo page. just copied this from theer  `$(".editorEx").jqte({css:"jqte_green", placeholder:"Please write, drag-drop, copy-paste somethings"});`

Comment: @charlietfl:Yes I understand this.The toolbar's components I don't know how to express this way

Comment: if default isn't what you want, add that option to object and change it. Defaults are shown in docs, as are possible values.

Answer (score 0):

See the uncompressed version of jquery te source code.
find this:

```
var vars = $.extend({
    // options
    'status'        : true,
    'css'           : "jqte",
    'title'         : true,
    'titletext'     : varsTitle,
    'button'        : "OK",
    'format'        : true,
...
}, options);
```

Copy and paste the default options to your jqte initialization, pick only buttons you want to disable and set them to false, for ex. I used this to keep just basic formatting:

```
$('[data-wysiwyg]').jqte({
    // options
    'format': false,
    'fsize': false,
    'ol': false,
    'ul': false,
    'outdent': false,
    'indent': false,
    'left': false,
    'center': false,
    'right': false,
    'rule': false
});
```

It is ugly and unintuitive, but as I've just found out, yet in 2014 most simple web wysiwygs are useless or have at least more serious trouble, jquery TE fitted my needs best.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods

1. using CSS

`.jqte_toolbar { display:none; }`

2. Using jqte options

   $('#txtArea').jqte({
   'format': false,
   'fsize': false,
   'ol': false,
   'ul': false,
   'outdent': false,
   'indent': false,
   'left': false,
   'center': false,
   'right': false,
   'rule': false,
   'unlink': false,
   'link': false,
   'u': false,
   'sup': false,
   'sub':false,
   'strike': false,
   'b': false,
   'i': false,
   'color': false,
   'source': false,
   'remove': false
   });

I prefer combining both because after using second method the small part of toolbar is still visible. I think about 2px. by turning off options, loading will be faster